# I'm Not able to find when the exhausted resultset occurs? And, how do you handle the following exception: Exhausted Resultset?

Tags: java, jdbc

Here `label` is the text on the `button`. I have used 4 `buttons` to retrieve the data from database in `rs.first()`, `rs.next()`, `rs.previous`, `rs.last();`. The `rs.first()` and `rs.last()` works fine. But not the `rs.next()` [works like `rs.first()`] and `rs.previous()`

[ExhaustedException]

What can i do now for that.

```
public EmployeeTo getEmployee(String label)throws Exception
{    
   rs=st.executeQuery("select * from Employee");
   if(rs!=null)
   {
      if(label.equals("First"))
      {
         rs.first();
      }
      else if(label.equals("Next"))`enter code here`
         rs.next();
      else if(label.equals("Previous"))
         rs.previous();
      else if(label.equals("Last"))
       rs.last();
       eto.setEno(rs.getInt(1));
       eto.setEname(rs.getString(2));
       eto.setEsal(rs.getFloat(3));
       eto.setEaddr(rs.getString(4));
    }
    else
       eto=null;    
    return eto;    
}
```

Comment: This really should be two separate posts.  Keep your questions here focused on one problem at a time.

Comment: Fixed some major issues with formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is completely wrong. The query is performed every time the method is called, so you simply can't call `rs.previous();`.

A quick fix would be to move the query outside of the method, but even then the code looks very dubious. What are you trying to do exactly?